# How to use elastic search for storing & fetching document as Json

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I am working on ElasticSearch for the purpose of storing & fetching data as json. The problem is ES treats json as text/string when I use search/highlight function and does not complete my requirement i.e. to get all the parents of stored json in the search result.
For example if I have a json like this:

`{"jsonfile.htm":{"Headingtag":"100129","Sectiontext":{"part i":{"Headingtag":"p1","Sectiontext":{"Random Heading I":{"Sectiontext":"Impossible considered invitation him men instrument saw celebrated unpleasant."},"Random Heading II":{"Sectiontext":"Prevailed discovery immediate objection of ye at."}}}}}}`

When we use search or highlight function for "celebrated" text, it gives me the result like this:

*[highlight] => Array
(
[detail] => Array
(
[0] => ":{"Random Heading I":{"Sectiontext":"Impossible considered invitation him men instrument saw celebrated
)
)*

It consider json as string and ignores the parent child relation.
**Can anyone help me to find out how to fetch all the searched text parents in the result?**

Comment: Sorry for my first post. What you want is to have a tree view from the root to the field like : Sectiontext.part i.Sectiontext.Random Heading I.Sectiontext": "Impossible considered invitation him men instrument saw celebrated unpleasant." ?

Comment: @Jaycreation yes it will work for me. I just want to get all parents of searched text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably just use the ability to use * in "highlight".
If i take your example:

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "celebrated",
      "fields": ["jsonfile.*"]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "jsonfile.*": {}
    }
  }
}
```

And the result will be:

```
{
        "_index" : "test-5",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "r4fdAXQBw1rncBcgXr08",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "jsonfile.htm" : {
            "Headingtag" : "100129",
            "Sectiontext" : {
              "part i" : {
                "Headingtag" : "p1",
                "Sectiontext" : {
                  "Random Heading I" : {
                    "Sectiontext" : "Impossible considered invitation him men instrument saw celebrated unpleasant."
                  },
                  "Random Heading II" : {
                    "Sectiontext" : "Prevailed discovery immediate objection of ye at."
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "jsonfile.htm.Sectiontext.part i.Sectiontext.Random Heading I.Sectiontext" : [
            "Impossible considered invitation him men instrument saw <em>celebrated</em> unpleasant."
          ]
        }
      }
```

Of course you can also disable the _source in your query if you don't use is.

Comment: It's working but useful only when we have indexed only json data. Is there any way to store other information like document_id, document_type etc along with the json data?

Comment: Yes, that was your use case I guess. 
About other datas, if they are on your source Field, you'll have to find them from here.  you have to add them on your doc at the ingest time.